# How to set client side timestamp in spring data cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, spring-data-cassandra

In datastax driver we have api like

> withTimestampGenerator(new AtomicMonotonicTimestampGenerator())

to enable the feature to setting timestamp per query at client side. How can we achieve same with spring data canssandra.

I am aware that i can use *"USING TIMESTAMP value"* in cql but is there something which spring data cassandra provide ? I dont find such api in CassandraClusterFactoryBean .

Answer (score 2):

You are correct!

Unfortunately, it appears SD *Cassandra* is missing a configuration option on the [CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/1.4.2.RELEASE/spring-cql/src/main/java/org/springframework/cassandra/config/CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean.java#L139-L189) class supporting the [withTimestampGenerator(:TimestampGenerator)](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#withTimestampGenerator-com.datastax.driver.core.TimestampGenerator-) configuration setting with the DataStax Java driver `Cluster.Builder` API.

Equally unfortunate is there is no workaround (other than the `USING TIMESTAMP` in CQL) at the moment either.

It also appears the `CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean` is missing configuration options for:

1. [Cluster.Builder.withAddressTranslator(:AddressTranslator)](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#withAddressTranslator-com.datastax.driver.core.policies.AddressTranslator-)
2. [Cluster.Builder.withClusterName(:String)](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#withClusterName-java.lang.String-)
3. [Cluster.Builder.withCodeRegistry(:CodecRegistry)](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#withCodecRegistry-com.datastax.driver.core.CodecRegistry-)
4. [Cluster.Builder.withMaxSchemaAgreementWaitSeconds(:int)](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#withMaxSchemaAgreementWaitSeconds-int-)
5. [Cluster.Builder.withSpeculativeExecutionPolicy(:SpeculativeExecutionPolicy)](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#withSpeculativeExecutionPolicy-com.datastax.driver.core.policies.SpeculativeExecutionPolicy-)

Though, beware, the [withTimestampGenerator(..)](http://docs.datastax.com/en/latest-java-driver-api/com/datastax/driver/core/Cluster.Builder.html#withTimestampGenerator-com.datastax.driver.core.TimestampGenerator-) is only supported in version 3 of the DataStax Java Driver, which the next version (i.e. **1.5.0**) of SD *Cassandra* will support...

> This feature is only available with version V3 or above of the native protocol. With earlier versions, timestamps are always generated server-side, and setting a generator through this method will have no effect.

Comment: NOTE: since the SD *Cassandra* API (i.e. `CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean`) does not support these configuration options, neither will the SD *Cassandra* XML namespace configuration meta-data (obviously).

Comment: Thanks for the reply John. So for now i will use USING TIMESTAMP only then.

Answer (score -1):

The timestamp capability is available in SD 1.5.x, 
  `public void setTimestampGenerator(TimestampGenerator timestampGenerator) {
        this.timestampGenerator = timestampGenerator;
    }`

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/cc4625f492c256e5fa3cb6640d19b4e048b9542b/spring-data-cassandra/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/cql/config/CassandraCqlClusterFactoryBean.java.